# what a micro-controller on low is really is ?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors

i am a beginner and i am playing with transistors to understand them before i use them with a micro controller, but knowing the reality of **electron flow** while everything is in term the conventional current is confusing especially with transistors, as i tested a **pnp transistor** with batteries, the base should be connected to the negative, while as i read how to use them with a Micro, they should be connected to a pin in low state.

So what does low really mean in sense of electron flow ?

Comment: Ignore electron flow. Use conventional current.

Comment: I'm really trying, but i can't help when i am learning something new, but to understand it first in the sense of electron flow. hhh

Comment: Well, then you need to get used to translating everything. It's like trying to drive a lefthand car in a righthand country. Low = most negative.

Comment: hhhh i know i'm just complicating things for myself, anyway thanks

Comment: The low state on a micro acts as a current **sink**. Current goes **into the output** and (is switched) down to ground (0V). The high state of a micro acts as a current **source** - you can take current **from** the output. Forget about electron flow, it doesn't help you understand the circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a microcontroller setting the base of a PNP, using a 6 volt battery.
[ I replaced the MCU by a switch, and 10Kohm pullup. ]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhkswN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: shouldn't R1 be between the base and switch as well?

Comment: With Base at 0.0 volts, the emitter will be 0.2 or 0.3 or 0.4 or 0.5 or 0.6 or 0.7 volts higher. Current is limited by the emitter resistor. Vbe increases by 0.058v for each 10X more Ie.